# Show the post date using the wp_get_archives() function?

Tags: functions, wp-get-archives

I have some doubt about the [`wp_get_archives()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

In my website I have create the following page template that use the `wp_get_archives()` function to show the posts list:

```
<?php 

    /**
     * Template Name: Posts Archive
     *
     * A custom page template for displaying all posts.
     *
     * The "Template Name:" bit above allows this to be selectable
     * from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
     *
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
     * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
     */

    get_header(); 

?>

<!-- Contenuti (griglia) -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Lead presentazione -->
    <section id="presentazione">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <!--<h1 class="text-center"><small>Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</small></h1>-->
                <h1 class="text-center title">Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</h1>
                <h1 class="text-center leadTitle">Association in Defense of the Human Rights of the Eritrean People</h1>
                <!--
                <p class="lead text-center">
                    Association in Defense of the Human Rights of the Eritrean People
                </p>
                -->
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </section><!-- /section presentazione -->
    <!-- Progetti in evidenza -->

    <header class="header-sezione">
        <h2>Archivio post</h2>
    </header>

    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=postbypost'); ?>
    </ul>

    </section>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It work and [this](http://lnx.asper-eritrea.com/archivio/) is the result (I only need to set the right CSS related to the font size)

Ok, now my question is: using the `wp_get_archives()` function can I show the post date before each posts?.

I want to obtain something like:

> 10/04/2014 - POST TITLE

rather than the mere post title.

Can I do it passing some parameters to the `wp_get_archives()` function? Or the only solution is do not use this function and create a custom loop into my template page?

Answer (score 0):

`wp_get_archives()` can not display post date, but you can force `wp_get_archives` to display date by using hook.

Put the following function at the end of your custom template file or functions.php file -

```
function wpse_the_title($title, $id){
    if( $date = get_the_date('d/m/Y', $id) ){
        $title = sprintf('%s - %s', $date, $title);
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Replace with appropriate code -

```
<?php add_filter('the_title', 'wpse_the_title', 10, 2); ?>
<ul>
    <?php wp_get_archives('type=postbypost'); ?>
</ul>
<?php remove_filter('the_title', 'wpse_the_title', 10, 2); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The wp_get_archives function in Wordpress does not support displaying dates. However my solution worked without using this function it's still probably handy for your or someone else his cause:

In the functions.php file of your theme place the following:

```
 function recentPostsDate() {
    $rPosts = new WP_Query();
    $rPosts->query('showposts=6');
    while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post(); ?>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php the_date('d/m/Y', '<span class="date">', '</span>'); the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

After this you can use this in your main template simply by calling the function:

```
<?php recentPostsDate(); ?>
```

Based upon the settings I have chosen the output will look something like:

> 01/04/2015  First news title
>  23/03/2015  2nd news title 
>  14/03/2015  Third news title 
> ...